# Model matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I received error:

```
WARNING:logger:invoice_settings_create_new_invoice ERROR: Invoice matching query does not exist.
```

This is error I  receive when try to call .save() method for object:

```
object = Invoice(name=so_name)
for fieldname, fieldvalue in invoice_data['fields'].items():
    if fieldvalue['type']=='relto':
        model_rel = object._meta.get_field(fieldname).rel.to
        setattr(object, fieldname, model_rel().objects.get(pk=int(fieldvalue['value'])))
    else:
        if (object._meta.get_field(fieldname).get_internal_type() == 'IntegerField'):
            setattr(object, fieldname, int(fieldvalue['value']))
        if (object._meta.get_field(fieldname).get_internal_type() == 'DecimalField'):
            setattr(object, fieldname, float(fieldvalue['value']))
        if (object._meta.get_field(fieldname).get_internal_type() == 'DateField'):
            setattr(object, fieldname, datetime.datetime.strptime(fieldvalue['value'], "%d.%m.%Y").date())
object.save()
```

I didn't use something complicate. I create new object. Set value for fields of object. Tried to save it. And received an error.
Why is it happening? How i can fix it?

**UPD**:

Modified code before .save():

```
logger.warning('object name: %s', object.name)
logger.warning('object fk: %s', object.tender_game_id.year_number)
object.save()
```

Error:

```
WARNING:logger:object name: INV-5542-2017/OP
WARNING:logger:object fk: 5542
WARNING:logger:invoice_settings_create_new_invoice ERROR: Invoice matching query does not exist.
```

**UPD2**:

If i only create object Invoice and try to save it i get some error:

```
object = Invoice(name=so_name)
logger.warning('object name: %s', object.name)
object.save()
```

Error:

```
WARNING:logger:object name: INV-5542-2017/OP
WARNING:logger:invoice_settings_create_new_invoice ERROR: Invoice matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: I think error is `model_rel().objects.get(pk=int(fieldvalue['value'])))`

Comment: Blurgh. Why are you writing code like this?

Comment: to  itzMEonTV this is error displayed on object.save().  model_rel().objects.get(pk=int(fieldvalue['value']) retrurn object for ForeignKey field.

Comment: to Daniel Roseman. What are you want to ask me? Do not like this code or do not understand why it is?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the code being edited by another developer. He modified method save() for Invoice() model.